# WiX - How can would I hard code the default install path?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, wix

I am trying to get the directory to be hard coded with WiX so that it can only go into one place. To prevent issues installing.

I cannot use [WindowsVolume] or [TARGETDIR] because the first is C: drive and the second defaults to the one with the most space available.

The path i need is on D: drive, how would I specifically say D: drive for my installer? Is there a variable for D or a way to get that drive letter?

Comment: Is my solution was helpful for u, if yes please mark as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the property RootDrive.

```
<Property Id="ROOTDRIVE" Value="D:\"/>
```